# Spread objects across 2 rows if already occupied - Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hey so Ive Been trying to figure this out but having no luck. Ive got 8 spawns that shuffle and they should spawn across 2 rows of 4. The issue I am having is that all 8 seem to just spawn only in the top row.

So basically this:
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]
                                                               [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]

When it should be this:
[1][2][3][4] 
[5][6][7][8]

I understand its to do with the fact that I am positioning each orb at Center on Y axis but not sure how I would make it so that if the 4 positions are occupied, then move down to the second row.

Cheers,

**Spawn code**

```
function spawnBase()
shuffleOrbArray(orbList)

for i=1, #orbList do
    local orbName = orbList[i]
    local posX = (i-1)*67+60  

    if orbName == "red" then

         redPlace = display.newImageRect("Shapes/red-placeholder.png", 57,57)
         redPlace.y = _H/2
         redPlace.x = posX
         redPlace.alpha = 1
         redPlace.id = "Red"             
         orbName:insert(redPlace)
         redPlace:addEventListener("tap", revealColor)

    elseif orbName == "green" then 
        --create green enemy

         greenPlace = display.newImageRect("Shapes/green-placeholder.png", 57,57)
         greenPlace.y = _H/2
         greenPlace.x = posX
         greenPlace.alpha = 1
         greenPlace.id = "Green"
         orbName:insert(greenPlace)
         greenPlace:addEventListener("tap", revealColor)

       elseif orbName == "yellow" then 
        --create green enemy
```

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that. _H/2 basically is display.content height divided by 2. It means center height.

Comment: You can update this value for `i>4`.

Comment: That works fine but just drops from that position onwards. The problem now is the X position. It just drops down from wherever it exceeded 4. I almost need it to reset its count but in the second row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
local cols = 4
local orbList = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" }

for i=1, #orbList do
    local c = ( i - 1 ) % cols
    local r = math.floor( ( i - 1 ) / cols)
    print( c, r, orbList[i] )

    local posX = c * sizeX
    local posY = r * sizeY
end
```

You can look here a game sample in Corona/Lua: https://github.com/estudiolune/corona-sdk/tree/master/br3ak

Comment: Hey Maicon, thanks for the help. What is sizeX and sizeY values of?

Comment: @DipeshDhanji size is values of your Orb (width,height).